# Parslet: SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby, parslet

I am working on a new programming language [*rip*](https://github.com/rip-lang/rip), and I'm having trouble getting to the bottom of some infinite loops. Is there a way to print out each rule as it gets called, such that I can see the rules that are recursing? I've tried walking through the code in my head, and I just don't see it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To flesh out [Raving Genius’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15651440/578288):

The method to patch is actually `Parslet::Atoms::Context#lookup`. [View it on GitHub](https://github.com/kschiess/parslet/blob/master/lib/parslet/atoms/context.rb#L96) ([permalink to current version](https://github.com/kschiess/parslet/blob/9d59363f14b0292676187287bee25d7b5ad06aa0/lib/parslet/atoms/context.rb#L96)). In your own code, you can patch that method to print `obj` like this:

```
class Parslet::Atoms::Context
  def lookup(obj, pos)
    p obj
    @cache[pos][obj.object_id]
  end
end
```

Run that code any time before you call `parse` on your parser, and it will take effect. Sample output:

```
>> parser = ConsistentNewlineTextParser.new
=> LINES
>> parser.parse("abc")
LINES
(line_content:LINE_CONTENT NEWLINE){0, } line_content:LINE_CONTENT
(line_content:LINE_CONTENT NEWLINE){0, }
line_content:LINE_CONTENT NEWLINE
LINE_CONTENT
WORD
\\w{0, }
\\w
\\w
\\w
\\w
NEWLINE
dynamic { ... }
FIRST_NEWLINE
'? '
'
'?
'
'
'
LINE_CONTENT
=> {:line_content=>"abc"@0}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: editing `Parslet::Atom::Context#lookup` to output the `obj` parameter will show each rule as it is being called.

Answer (score 0):

[My branch of Parslet](https://github.com/nigelthorne/parslet) automatically detects endless loops, and exits out reporting expression that is repeating without consuming anything.

https://github.com/nigelthorne/parslet

see [Parse markdown indented code block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485292/parse-markdown-indented-code-block) for an example.